# WPF Prism RegisterTypeForNavigation with viewmodel type

Tags: wpf, prism

In WPF + Prism, how can I navigate to a strongly type object using view-model type:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync<MainPageviewModel>();
```

For this to work I suppose I'd need something like this:

```
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need this

```
 Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>();
```

to be able to navigate, then you probably want viewmodellocator (on the xaml) to create you the viewmodel.

This is how you send parameters

```
var navigationParameters = new NavigationParameters();

navigationParameters.Add("ParameterKey","TheParameter")

RegionManager.RequestNavigate("YouRegionName", new Uri(nameOf(MainPage),   UriKind.Relative), navigationParameters);
```

when you receive them, you have to check the navigationContext in OnNavigatedTo method and access them by the key.

Comment: You don't even need to register the ViewModel with the container, the ViewModelLocator uses a naming convention to resolve the ViewModel.  So if I have a Views/MainView.xaml the ViewModels/MainViewModel.cs will be automatically resolved.

Comment: @StephenWilson Thank you for your comment, I did not know you don't have to register ViewModel with the container. I will have to relook at my own code now, because I have lots of viewmodels and interfaces registered this way. And if there is no need for it, then great :) Thank you again. Ps. I've updated the answer.

Comment: thank you both ! how would the RequestNavigate look like in this? Ideally I'd like to pass the view-model type. I couldn't find simple examples. I see what I want implemented for Xamarin Forms, but not for WPF https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/Xamarin.Forms/3-NavigationService.md

Comment: If passing the view-model type is too complicated, how would RequestNavigate looks like? what do I need to pass? just region name and view-type string?

Comment: @adminSoftDK thank you. I don't like having to specify the region, I will open a separate question

Comment: does the naming convention which @StephenWilson mentioned works only if you have prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True" ?
I have a UserControl with a region set on a ContentControl, and it does not create the view-model for the control which goes inside it. I tried setting the AutoWireViewModel on Window, view-model doesn't get created

Comment: @DonBox thats correct it needs to be set to true. But I would suggest to google it, there are lots of things about it.