# How to navigate in Xamarin cross platform application?

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms

I am building xamarin cross platform portable application using following steps:

1. Added service reference.
2. On button click in login page ,I used to validate user from db,if successful then move to next page else show up message.

Here is the code.

Login.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FypXFP.Login">
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="UserName" />
            <Entry x:Name="tbuserentry" Placeholder="UserName"></Entry>
            <Label Text="Password"></Label>
            <Entry x:Name="Pwd" IsPassword="True" Placeholder="Password"></Entry>
            <Button x:Name="Save" Clicked="Save_Clicked" Text="Login"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Login.cs.xaml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace FypXFP
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        private FypXFP.ServiceReference1.CMSServiceClient _client;
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Save_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.43.101/FYP_Admin/webservices/cmsservice.svc");
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
            {
                Name = "basicHttpBinding",
                MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647
            };

            TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
            binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
            binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
            binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;

            _client = new FypXFP.ServiceReference1.CMSServiceClient(binding, endpoint);

            string uname = tbuserentry.Text.Trim();
            string password = Pwd.Text.Trim();
            _client.ValidateUserAsync(uname, password);
            _client.ValidateUserCompleted += _client_ValidateUserCompleted;

        }
        public async void Redirect(Boolean Result)
        {
            if (Result == true)
            {
                Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new TicketPage(), this);
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Something wrong", "Cancel");
            }
        }
        private void _client_ValidateUserCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.ValidateUserCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result == true)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    Redirect(true);
                });


            }
            else
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    Redirect(false);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is if I entered incorrect credentials,than alert does show up, but on other hand if entered correct credentials, then show up

> Unhandle Exception

I have tried all possible solutions.

Comment: is your page contained within a NavigationPage?

Comment: Please clarify this point,i have created page on the root of ppl project

Comment: the Navigation property will be null if your page is not contained within a NavigationPage. See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/

Comment: like Jason said : Try this :Navigation.PushAsync(new TicketPage()); to see if it is contained within a navigation.

Comment: You need to register the page for navigation... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38431311/wpf-prism-registertypefornavigation-with-viewmodel-type